# Having a small issue adding CSS to some JS

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to convert the following CSS

```
img.rsImg.rsMainSlideImage {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Into Javascript

```
$('img').closest('.rsImg').closest('.rsMainSlideImage').css('display', 'inline-block');
```

And something I'm doing seems to be a bit off. I used the same script with a single div and it worked, but this is a bit nested.

Comment: add your HTML markup as well.

Comment: The `closest()` method seeks outward. Why aren't you simply putting your selector in the initial argument?

Comment: Also, add any css stylesheet you have that may be affecting this or it's outer HTML.  You may have another style overriding what you are attempting manipulate here.

Comment: @isherwood, this is only going to find a `.rsMainSlideImage` with a child `.rsImg` with a child `img`. :))

Comment: Not the CSS rule. The CSS rule matches an image with the classes `rsMainSlideImage` and `rsImg`. `closest()` searches up the DOM.

Comment: Also, I'm telling the OP, just in way of responding to your comment. I'm not giving _you_ jquery lessons, I'm giving wesley them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

```
$("img.rsImg.rsMainSlideImage").css("display", "inline-block");
```

Comment: Ended up going with the following, It ends up getting overwritten by royalslider on load. .rsContent {
    visibility: hidden;
}